# Will const instance remain in memory after a Stateful widget gets disposed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

A const variable will only be created once. When I try to create the same variable, the old variable will be returned. Thus, no new memory allocation occurs.

For example, if I create `const Icon(Icons.add)` and later try to use `const Icon(Icons.add)` in another class, the old one will be returned.

But my question is: if I use `const Icon(Icons.add)` in a stateful widget, will this memory allocation be present forever even after the stateful widget is disposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an instance created using `const` will never be garbage collected.

The instance is in fact created at the compilation and present in the binary.

Comment: The questions implies that this instance gets stored in memory. You said that it is part of the compiled binary. These two things do not quite match up. I would still ask myself if it ever gets loaded into memory and if yes, if it gets garbage collected once no longer needed.

Comment: it is in the binary, then in the memory as soon as the app is started.

Comment: what about final ?